# Shopify Custom Text box according to product collection

Tags: collections, conditional-statements, shopify

Im trying to do a conditional where if a product is in collection "personal" it will show a text box. I have this in the product.liquid page but it does't seem to be working.

```
   {% if collection.title == 'personal' %}
            <div>                             
              <p><input type="text" id="letter" placeholder="Enter up to 6 Letters" name="properties[letter]" /></p>
            </div>
   {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for collection in product.collections %}
  {% if collection.handle == 'personal' %}
    <div>                             
      <p><input type="text" id="letter" placeholder="Enter up to 6 Letters" name="properties[letter]" /></p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See the Shopify docs for [`product.collections`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/product#product-collections).

Comment: Do you know how to then display this property in the cart.liquid?

Comment: @mariovass [See this tutorial](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization#updating-cart-liquid) in the Shopify docs, particularly the section "Updating cart.liquid".